# overflow flag required in signed compares?

Tags: assembly

i am implementing a custom 16bit cpu (in verilog). I'm having trouble wrapping my head around if I need to implement an overflow flag to handle signed compares.

In my current implementation I am only checking the result for zero and the sign bit to determine the result of compares:

```
when comparing x to y the ALU calculates: x - y (2's compl)
If the sign bit is set and the result is not zero y > x
If the sign bit is not set and the result is not zero x > y
```

I am not using an overflow flag to determine the outcome of the compares. I have tried many different values for x and y and they all come out correct.

Can signed compare be implemented without an overflow flag? If not, could you give me values for x and y that would give the wrong result this way?

Comment: What kind of numbers have you tried?

Comment: @EOF f.e. 0xa000 (-24k) and 0xb000 (-20k). And most combinations of 0xf000, 0xff00, 0x8000, 0x7000, 0x8400, 0x0f00, 0x1700, 0xf000...

Comment: Did you try `INT_MIN` (`0x8000`) and `1` (`0x1`)? `INT_MIN - 1` will overflow and create `INT_MAX` ( `0x7FFF`), which is nonzero and doesn't have the sign-bit set, which according to your table would indicate `INT_MIN > 1`.

Comment: I would think 0x8000 (-32k) minus 1 in 2's complement would be 0x8001, thus the sign bit would be set. Thus the result is correct. I just ran it, and the result is correct...

Comment: *Why* do you belive `0x8000 - 0x1` to be `0x8001` rather than `0x7FFF`? Can you provide some reasoning for this?

Comment: you are right its 7fff and it does not trigger (had my operands switched due to all the testing). So does this mean you always need to check for overflow to do signed compares?

Comment: You do need an overflow flag, fortunately it's really easy to implement anyway (take the XOR of the carry into the msb and the carry out of the msb).

Comment: and then add a jump if signed carry, jump if not (if V or not V) plus other combinations of V and N.

Comment: it can also be determined from the sign bits of the inputs and the output.  exercise for the reader...the xor is the easiest unless you use a canned module for addition (or let the verilog do it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

The "sign" bit does not help you for checking if x > y. You need the "carry" bit as you can see using 8-bit unsigned arithmetic:

```
132 - 2 = 130 (sign bit set, carry clear)
132 - 6 = 126 (sign bit clear, carry clear)
6 - 132 = 130 (sign bit set, carry set)
2 - 132 = 126 (sign bit clear, carry set)
```

(Replace "132" by "-124" and you see that it also won't work with signed arithmetic.)

Your actual question:

It depends, what exactly you want to ask:

If it is possible to design a CPU that can do signed comparison only having an instruction set allowing unsigned comparison:

In this case the answer is yes - as you can read in the comments to your answer. Simply invert the uppermost bit of both numbers (using a `XOR` operation) before doing the `CMP` operation.

If you want to know how many "flag" bits you need so a conditional jump based on a signed comparison is possible with (only) a `CMP` instruction and a conditional jump instruction:

You will need at least 3 flags: "Zero", "Carry" and a third one allowing you to calculate the value "Sign XOR Overflow".

(So you might use the "SignXorOverflow" flag.)

Because "Overflow" cannot be calculated from "Zero", "Carry" and "Sign" you will need the "Overflow" bit if you want to have the "Sign" bit.